# Error while trying to run a code in mininet environment "Import Error,no module named mininet"

Tags: python, python-3.x, sdn, mininet

I have installed mininet in my /home/user directory and my .py script to be run in /home/user/EE297B/ directory and also created a venv project file using PyCharm in /home/user/EE297B/ directory and try to run the .py code in there and I get the error import module mininet not found.I tried adding the path /home/user/mininet to sys.path of python as referenced by other similar questions on this portal.But I am still getting the same error.Some help is highly appreciated.

import error no module named mininet

[image]

Comment: You need to tell python where to find the mininet package. In PyCharm run configuration add in an environment variable for `PYTHONPATH` containing `/home/user/mininet`. I'm assuming the python package is there.

Comment: Yup it's there. I had done a similar project and used the interpreter variable path as Python2.7(Load_Balancer)/usr/bin/python2.7 and its working perfectly fine with that.But for Python3.5(EE297B)-/EE297B/venv/bin/python, its not working. Can you please make me understand whats the difference between these two and where actually i failed in my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
When I run the following:

```
sudo python topo.py
```

I receive the same error that no module named 'XXXXX'.

In my Linux, there is also another version of Python (version 3.6).
Since the mininet modules had been stored in the path related to this version, the following command helped me.

```
sudo python3.6 topo.py
```